# configure ubuntu to unsuspend when connected to power

Tags: ubuntu, usb, laptop, power-management

I have a frame.work ubuntu 21.10 laptop that I connect often to a usb-c hub that has a monitor, keyboard and mouse.

I currently pull my laptop out and plug in the usb-c hub but then open the laptop lid to un suspend, then close the lid to make my main monitor the only display.

I'd like to put the laptop in a holder that would make it difficult to connect to power and open the lid.

When the laptop lid is closed and on battery power, I'd like the laptop to suspend.
When the laptop lid is closed and connected to ac power, I'd like the laptop to wake so that I can use it as soon as possible.
When the laptop lid is closed and I disconnect ac power, I'd like the laptop to suspend after a few minutes.

If the laptop is connected to AC power, I'd like the power profile set to maximum.
If the laptop is on battery, I'd like the power profile set to energy saver.

Is there any app or setting that does this? If not, how do I catch these events and set a service to manage these states?

Comment: You do realize that suspend drains the battery? It is not hibernation, but keeps the CPU alive.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That is incorrect. Sleep/suspend to RAM is ACPI S3, in which only the RAM is kept powered.

Comment: Usually you can change the behavior in your devices BIOS settings if it is supported. For waking it up what you are looking for is "Power on AC connect" or "Wake on USB device" or similar.

Comment: Argh. I'm looking and don't see an option in the bios. I've tested all the settings I can find and I was hoping something at the OS level could catch and trigger.

Comment: I've set the power on AC attach in the bios, but this doesn't trigger a wake from sleep. 
I've tried also whitelisting my USB hubs in TLP to see if mouse or keyboard action would help.